# How to convert a column inside a Gravity Forms List to a multi-file upload?

Tags: php, wordpress, multifile-uploader, gravityforms

I have a problem regarding how to convert a column inside a Gravity Form List field to a multi-file upload, I tried using the code below I found online and it is not converting the column input into a multi file upload.

I also tried using the plugin "Ajax Upload" but this only support single file upload.

```
add_filter( 'gform_multifile_upload_field', 'create_custom_file_upload_field', 10, 3 ); 
function create_custom_file_upload_field( $field, $form, $field_id ) {
    $field = new GF_Field_FileUpload( array(
        'id'                => $field_id,
        'multipleFiles'     => true,
        'maxFiles'          => 5,
        'maxFileSize'       => '',
        'allowedExtensions' => 'csv'     
    ) );

   return $field;
}
```

I should be able to make a column into a multi-file upload and the selected file URLs should reflect on the Gravity VIEW.

Comment: Uploading multiple files is possible using the build-in functionality already, you just need to specify this in the field options. To have the entries list in the backend display the file download URLs directly in the field’s column, what you have above would be the wrong hook to begin with - for that, you probably rather need something like https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_entry_list_columns/

Comment: Yes I am aware of the multi-file upload in gravity forms, but not inside a List Field ( the one under "Advanced Fields" ). The list field can only accept single line text input, but can also accept other input types through the use of plugins like Ajax Upload for single file upload. My problem is how to make a column inside a list field ( not the entry list ) a multifile upload ).

Comment: Then you probably want to start with https://docs.gravityforms.com/gf_field_list/ But I am not sure if that actually allows to insert different field types into a List field. If your “Ajax Upload” add-on is capable of achieving _that_, then check the source code to figure out how it does that.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I'm aware of that supports including "repeating" multi file upload fields is my [Gravity Forms Nested Forms](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/). You would use this instead of a List field.